# rsync backup not creating any files

Tags: rsync, backup

I am trying to run `rsync` to back up my file system to an external flash drive. It finishes almost immediately, and no files are present on the flash drive when I view it. What am I doing wrong?

```
king@death-star ~/Scripts $ sudo rsync -aAXv --info=progress2 --exclude={"/media/king/Mint-backup/*"} /media/king/Mint-backup/mint_backup_1.3.16
sending incremental file list
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/01/03 00:02:41 mint_backup_1.3.16
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#0, to-chk=0/1)

sent 82 bytes  received 82 bytes  328.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

I am on Linux Mint 17.3 and following a guide from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync). This is my first attempt at backing up to the recently formatted ext4 flashdrive.

Comment: That command line doesn't seem to have a source and destination, just what looks like it should be the destination? (The guide copies from `/*`.)

Comment: Ahhh....did you consult the man page for rsync?

Comment: Yep.... cant believe I missed the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is not complete. You did not mention the source.

For example, let's say :

You want to backup : **/**

You want to exclude (folder that you do not want to backup):  **/dev, /proc, /sys, /tmp, /run, /lost+found, /mnt and /media**

Your backup location is : **/mnt/media/myFlashDrive**

Your command should be like :

```
sudo rsync -aAXv --info=progress2 --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /*  /mnt/media/myFlashDrive
```

As explain on the link you provided, it is recommended not to backup some of those folders as they are only created when system boot or other folders to avoid the loop. But, it's all depend on your needs and setup.

Therefore, the link should enough to give you all the explanation that you may have [Full system backup with Rsync Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync)